# How to filter dataframe by values with count more than specific value in the entire sheet?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame as follows

```
Genes   s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9  s10
AB1     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
GB2     1   0   0   25  0   10  0   0   5   0
AB3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
hB5     0   0   50  0   66  0   88  15  0   0
OB6     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB7     25  40  30  45  44  15  0   80  85  10
UB8     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
YB9     0   1   0   5   1   0   5   4   2   2
AB10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
TB11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB12    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to filter the genes that have count more than 10 at least in 4 samples

The expected output is

```
Genes   s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9  s10
hB5     0   0   50  0   66  0   88  15  0   0
AB7     25  40  30  45  44  15  0   80  85  10
```

I tried following code but it did not give the expected results

```
import pandas as pd
counts = pd.read_excel("rna.xlsx")
counts = counts[(counts > 0).sum(axis=1) >= 4]
counts.to_csv("output.tsv", sep="\t", header=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values by `10` instead by `0`, also if first column is not converted to index add `index_col=0`:

```
counts = pd.read_excel("rna.xlsx", 
                        index_col=0)


counts = counts[(counts > 10).sum(axis=1) >= 4]
print (counts)
       s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9  s10
Genes                                         
hB5     0   0  50   0  66   0  88  15   0    0
AB7    25  40  30  45  44  15   0  80  85   10
```